# DELETE method in rest-api throws exception: Too few args, expected 3 but got 2

Tags: rest, marklogic

I have created a Resource Service Extension in ML 6.0-3.2 as follows:

Created an xquery module named export-customer.xqy with a delete method (other method are omitted):

```
    declare function expctrl:delete(
        $context as map:map,
        $params as map:map,
        $input as document-node()?
    ) as document-node()? {
        let $customer := map:get($params, "customer")
        let $_ := exp:customer-node-delete(xs:int($customer))
        return ( xdmp:set-response-code(200, "OK"), () )
    };
```

Installed with the following command:

`curl --anyauth --user user:pass -X PUT -d@/opt/export-customer.xqy -HContent-Type:application/xquery "http://server1:8020/v1/config/resources/exportCustomer?title=exportCustomer&method=get&method=put&method=post&method=delete&get:customer=xs:string&delete:customer=xs:string"`

Invoked with the following command:

`curl --anyauth --user user:pass -X DELETE "http://server1:8020/v1/resources/exportCustomer?rs:customer=105"`

The result of this call is the following:

```
<rapi:error xmlns:rapi="http://marklogic.com/rest-api"><rapi:status-code>500</rapi:status-code><rapi:status>INTERNAL ERROR</rapi:status><rapi:message-code>XDMP-TOOFEWARGS</rapi:message-code><rapi:message>XDMP-TOOFEWARGS: (err:XPST0017) xdmp:function(fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/exportCustomer", "delete"))($context, $resource-params) -- Too few args, expected 3 but got 2.  See the MarkLogic server error log for further detail.</rapi:message></rapi:error>
```

The stack trace leads to line 410 of the resource-model-update.xqy module:

```
        if (empty($tx-ids))
->      then rsrcmodupd:exec-delete-impl($headers,$endpoint-params,$responder)
        else
```

I am at a loss as to what approach to take to even try and debug this.  It is not making it to my code yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says that the function wants three params but the REST API is calling it with two params. It also says to take a look at the ErrorLog.txt for more details.

I see that you modeled your function declaration on an example at http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions#id_75991 in the docs. Just a guess, but maybe the docs are wrong? Try removing the $input parameter from your function declaration. If you think about it, why would a DELETE include that?

Comment: It turns out your guess was correct.  Removing the third parameter: `$input as document-node()*` worked like a charm.